# How can I interpret my heatmap for gene analysis?

Tags: r, heatmap

What is the difference if create a heatmap using the basic function heatmap() or ggplot2?

How is the Z score automatically created on heatmap?
And do we interpret the heatmap?

My heatmap looks like this:
[Heatmap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XSAGI.png)